# Code not responding accordingly to the parameters passed via the browser

Tags: php

I put the following code in the browser `?phase=1&step=0&fot=false` and I get a black page.
with the PHP error

> Undefined variable: fOT in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\1.php on line 219

This is the `$this->createTablePages ($fOT);` line. If I change it to `$this->createTablePages ($this->fOT)` I get the following error

> Undefined property: phase2::$fOT in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\1.php on line 219

I know that `$this->IDB3 = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB3;` in the __constructor is right. How do I do that?

```
class phase2 {
        function __construct () {

        $dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';
        $this->dbFile = $dbFile;
        include_once ("$this->dbFile"); 


        $step = $_GET["step"];

        $username = $DB_USER;
        $password = $DB_PASS;
        $server = $DB_SERVER;
        $dbName = $DB_NAME;

        $this->step = $step;
        $this->dbFile = $dbFile;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;

        $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=' .$server.';dbname='.$this->dbName,$this->username,$this->password);

        $this->db = $db;

        if (empty ($_GET['fot']) ) { 
        $fOT = 'false'; 
        } elseif ($_GET['true']) { $fOT = 'true'; }

        $this->IDB = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB;
        $this->IDB2 = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB2;
        $this->IDB3 = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB3;
        }



public function handleDatabase (){
// Prepare SQL Statements
    $IDB = $this->db->prepare( 
         "CREATE TABLE pages (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
         subject_id int(11) NOT NULL,
          menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          position int(3) NOT NULL,
          visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          content text NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    $IDB2 = $this->db->prepare("
        CREATE TABLE subjects (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          position int(3) NOT NULL,
          visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    $IDB3 = $this->db->prepare("
        CREATE TABLE users (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          hashed_password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
}
//Set Option to True or False

function createTablePages ($fOT){

    $r1 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'page\'');
    if (count($r1->fetchAll()) > 0 && $fOT === 'false') {
        echo "The table PAGE exists";

    } elseif ($fOT === 'true') {
        $this->IDB->execute;
                $this->stepFunction (1,false);
    }
}
function createTableSubjects ($fOT){

    $r2 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'subjects\'');
    if (count($r2->fetchAll()) > 0  && $fOT === 'false') {
        echo "The table SUBJECTS exists ";

    } elseif ($fOT === 'true') {

        $this->IDB2->execute;
        $this->stepFunction (2,false);

    }
}

function createTableUsers ($fOT){

    $r3 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'users\'');   
    if (count($r3->fetchAll()) > 0  && $fOT === 'false') {
        echo "The table USERS exists";
    } elseif ($fOT === 'true') {
        $this->IDB3->execute;
        echo "Would you like to populate all the tables?";
    }   
}


public function stepFunction ($step, $fOT){

switch ($step) {
    case 0: 
            $this->createTablePages ($fOT);
            break;
    case 1: 
            $this->createTableSubjects($fOT);
            break;
    case 2: $this->createTableUsers ($fOT);
            break;
    }


}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
} elseif ($fOT = 'true') {
```

`=` is an **assignment**. You want the *comparison operator* `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($r1->fetchAll()) > 0 && $fOT = 'false') {
```

You've gotten confused between the assignment operator and the comparison one. You need to change that to:

```
if (count($r1->fetchAll()) > 0 && $fOT === 'false') {
```

An assignment operation returns the assigned value, so it's probably not going to give you the result you were expecting, as well as messing up the rest of the logic.

Comment: To be pedantic: The assignment operator returns the assigned value, not necessarily `true`. `$foo = false` is `false`. :)

Comment: ooopps :P... I did that and now i get a blank page with nothing in it. reglardless of weather i put true or false in the browser

Comment: @JonathanThurft, blank page (assuming IIS) means a PHP error (in most cases).

Comment: @deceze - thank you, I'll amend my answer. I suspect that it's not pedantry when it actually makes an answer incorrect :D

Comment: I changed my main post to display my current problem

Comment: @JonathanThurft Please don't completely alter your question/problem after you have already received answers for it. Please open a new question if necessary, but before that, please take the time to properly understand and debug your code. Thanks.